# Button no hidden to display the keyboard

Tags: android, button, keyboard, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a problem aligning a button at the bottom of the screen, this button is always kept in that position, and I have a scrollView that fills the screen .
The scrollView has EditText and the problem is when I press on a EditText, automatically have to move the EditText and placed on the keyboard, but in this case the button that was at the bottom is placed on the keyboard

This is how the currently displayed

[as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHlez.png)

This is how you should show the EditText should be placed above the keyboard to write smoothly, and the button should not be shown

[as it should be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJEjZ.png)

This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linScroll"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="2"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="5"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="6"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt7"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="7"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt8"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="8"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt9"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="9"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt10"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="10"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt11"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="11"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt12"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="12"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt13"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="13"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt14"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="14"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt15"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="15"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt16"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt17"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt18"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="18"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt19"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:hint="19"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt20"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="SOY UN BOTON"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="4" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="5" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="6" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="7" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="8" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="9" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="10" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="11" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="12" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="13" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="14" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="15" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="16" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="17" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="18" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="19" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="20" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="SOY UN BOTON" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is setting the weight of your button and changing the height of both the button and the scroll view to 0dp you should avoid using dp when setting the layout proportionality (if your using weights).

Second if you are just trying to get the app to not push the layout up when the soft keyboard is opened (that's why the button is appearing right above the soft keyboard) set

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I add 'android: windowSoftInputMode = " adjustPan"' in the manifest indeed keyboard appears on the button, but this error appears at the top of the screen:  http://oi61.tinypic.com/2vuyk94.jpg

Comment: Does it fix itself when you dismiss the soft keyboard?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of trying is instead of adjustPan try adjustUnspecified I don't know if that will work though. If it is fixing itself when you dismiss the keyboard that is normal operation. What adjust pan does is push the entire layout up to put the current EditText in the view. What you are seeing is a consequence of androids menu bar being transparent. This is a list of all tags for the input mode - > http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft (its all the way at the bottom)

Comment: adjustPan is trying to move the entire layout up, so this shift occurs another solution I've been reviewing is placed on the manifest adjustUnspecified and move the scroll to a certain position with pressed EditText visible